# verify.js - Attempts to validate elements that have been removed from the DOM

Tags: forms, element, verify

I'm using verify.js to validate my forms.

- https://github.com/jpillora/verifyjs/issues

Some forms allow users to dynamically add in elements and then remove them. My problem is, if they add in a new form element, try to submit it and the validation fails, then delete the element from the DOM, then submit again, verify.js is still trying to validate the removed elements.

Anyone had any experience of this?